# Nginx - Redirect many subdomains to a static Local IP

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have a VM with a set a servicies, all configurated in the same domain (Ej: `*.local-mml.cloud`), and I want to acces from my own PC, so I tried to use Nginx to redirect all to the local ip, but didn't work.

I dont realy know all the domains that I have to redirect, so becouse of that I want to use something that say '*All with `.local-mml.cloud` go to `192.168.x.x`*'

I tried this (but didn't work):

```
server {
        server_name     *.local-mml.cloud;

        location / {
            proxy_pass      https://192.168.217.128;
        }
    }
```

I also tried setting each one in the `/host` file (in Windows), that's work but are to many and always find one more.

> Aside notes: The VM have NAT network configuration, so is like a a
>   local network, because of that have an IP like 192.168.x.x.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect i.e. the browser goes `local-mml.cloud` and there is a 301 redirect to `https://192.168.217.128` or are you trying to proxy to that IP i.e. browser talks to `local-mml.cloud` but the server gets the content from `https://192.168.217.128`?

Comment: Yes, like a 301... Actualy I trying to do a DNS basically, all the content with the domain `local-mml.cloud` is in `192.168.217.128`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 server {

        listen   80 default_server;
        server_name *.local-mml.cloud;
        client_body_timeout 5s;
        client_header_timeout 5s;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass hhttps://192.168.217.128/;
        }

}
```